# Image gray after encoding Base64

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, base64

I'm encoding my image (byte[]) in Android to Base64 and sending it via REST (PUT) to my JEE server. After that i decode it on the JEE server to a byte[] and put it into a MySQL database (BLOB).

Android:

```
String foto= Base64.encodeToString(foto, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

JEE:

```
BASE64Decoder dec = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedFoto = dec.decodeBuffer(foto);
```

Then with another GET Request im requesting the same image: The picture is encoded on the JEE Server to Base64 and is send as a JSON to my Android, on which i decode it again to a byte[].

JEE:

```
BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
String foto = enc.encode(decodedFoto);
```

Android:

```
byte[] endFoto = Base64.decode(base64Foto, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now after this whole process i'm displaying my image but only the first pixels are colored and the rest is pure gray.

Comment: It looks like you're using `import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;` and `import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;`?  You shouldn't be.  If you're using JDK8, it now has built in encode/decode or use apache commons.  Neither of these suggestions may help you out but worth a try.  If they don't work I'm guessing it's something with the get bytes, maybe you need to specify like "UTF8" all around if possible?

Comment: @JGlass thanks for the tipp but the built in encode/decode didn't work out. It didn't work. I got a exception for decoding it with the built-in JDK8 decode methods. But you may be right and the byte[] is not in the right format. I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you get it figured out!